# Squeel query comparing 2 variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, squeel

#### Using squeel, I'm able to generate the following request

```
Payment.joins(:account => :preference).where({:account => {:preference => {:currency => :currency } } }).to_sql
=> SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "payments"."account_id" INNER JOIN "preferences" ON "preferences"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" WHERE "preferences"."currency" = "preferences"."currency"
```

#### However, how to get? (CHANGE IN CAPITAL)

```
=> SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "payments"."account_id" INNER JOIN "preferences" ON "preferences"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" WHERE "preferences"."currency" = "PAYMENTS"."currency"
```

If the solution work fine with meta_where as well that's even better ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to IRC guys hron84, injekt and SIGe

Here's the solution :

```
Payment.joins(:account => :preference).where{account.preference.currency == ~currency }.to_sql
```

Comment: Looks like blocks doesn't work with meta_where (the predecessor of squeel), if you need such thing with meta_where use : `Payment.joins(:account => :preference).where("\`preferences\`.\`currency\` = \`payments\`.\`currency\`").to_sql`